# Run .asm and .c files from a C program driver

Tags: c, driver

I am trying to write a program driver in C that will run another C file and a .asm assembly language file.
I have the files included in visual studio. If I run this driver program then visual studio will open a prompt and ask me if I want to open these files in another instance of visual studio, rather than run the files and return.
I know I must use the system call function, but I'm not sure how to do it in a way that actually makes them execute.

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    system("prog1.c");
    system("prog1.asm");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't "run" those source code files. They need to be compiled / assembled first, which is why the file name extensions `.c` and `.asm` are associated with a tool which does that.

Comment: I must write a driver that runs both of these files and counts the time for each to run. So first i am trying to run them. So i would have to use the compiled source files for this? The only way would be to turn them into .exe files first?

Comment: Yes. The next question is - do you compile the C code with optimizations or not? It will make a difference for measuring execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have shown is the content of another `.c` file isn't it?
You cannot "run" that `.c` file either; instead you are using visual studio to turn it into an executeable.
The executable is called `whatever.exe` or something and you can call it from prompt as `whatever.exe`, not as `whatever.c`.

The same is true for the system call.

Use the same method to turn your `prog1.c` into a `prog1.exe` and then call it from prompt. If that works you can also call it via `system()`.